# If any ruby app depend on older Version Rubygem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If any ruby app depend on older Version Rubygem?
like this:
   may be ,in this situation, there are some ruby app call some api of the older VERSION of RubyGem,but i have a latest Vesrion of RubyGem installed in my system.

So,shall we installed  both two VERSION(latest and older)  Rubygems in my sysytem?
And how can i make this true?I mean that if i "apt-get install Rubygems --xxVersion",
can the app find it and call the api of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you should be using Bundler, create a Gemfile in the root directory of your project and list your gems (and versions) there, then use "bundle exec" to invoke your ruby scripts.

This explains it better than I can http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Very much thank you for you answer .I want ask if i have an app which depends on a gem, but there are two version of the gem in my system.  How did the app know which version to use?

Comment: Bundler will generate `Gemfile.lock` with versions of all dependencies and then it will load only these versions for the app.